# Regex to get method parameter name

Tags: regex, regex-group

Need regular expression to replace only parameter name.
By program i am able to fetch the parameter name but while replacing it using regular exression , its failing when we have both parameter class and parameter name as same.
like below method:
`getCustomerCyclesListInfo(  CustomerCyclesListInfo CustomerCyclesListInfo,     CustomerCyclesListInfo CustomerCyclesListInfo)`

i tried with below regex but its matching all four in above :
`(?<!\()\b(CustomerCyclesListInfo)\b`

i want that word starting with ( (opening parenthesis) space or ,(coma) space should not be considered while capturing.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
\bCustomerCyclesListInfo(?= *[,)])
```

See [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/sEYBO2ryxq).

Comment: can u please also update the above regex if i have space after the parameter name also , as its not matching `( CustomerCyclesListInfo CustomerCyclesListInfo ,   CustomerCyclesListInfo CustomerCyclesListInfo )` if we have space between parameter name and , or )

Comment: i tried with `(\bCustomerCyclesListInfo)((?=(\s*,))|(?=(\s*\))))`  can it be refined more ?

Comment: @SandeepChauhan done. see updated regex and demo link

Comment: thanks for help , its simple to understand and what i want :)